# String variable is not returning properly in C

Tags: c, string, function, return, return-value

I have been trying to make a function, `is_isogram`, return a value that is an alphabetized string. When I pass the value through the function from `main`, the variable to be returned is set to the correct value.

However, when I return the variable from the function, it does not return anything in `main`. Along with this, I get an error for `unable to read memory` when I initialize the variable to hold the return value in `main`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "isogram.h"

char  is_isogram(char phrase[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; phrase[i]; i++) {
        tolower(phrase[i]);
    }

    if (phrase == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    char temp;
    int count1;
    int count2;
    char *alphabet = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(phrase) + 1));
    int n = strlen(phrase);
    for (count1 = 0; count1 < n - 1; count1++) {
        for (count2 = count1 + 1; count2 < n; count2++) {
            if (phrase[count1] > phrase[count2]) {
                temp = phrase[count1];
                phrase[count1] = phrase[count2];
                phrase[count2] = temp;
                alphabet = phrase;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return alphabet;
}
```

This function does not return the variable `alphabet`. I have been trying to use `malloc` and other techniques to return this local variable as a value. I wanted to use every character string as an array with "[]," however I would get errors about needing to initialize an array. The value returned is currently just a sizeable garbage value, however, when I step through the process of debugging, the variable `alphabet` is 'abb.'

```
int main() {
    char *bet = is_isogram("bab\0");
    if (bet == 'abb\0') {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The variable `bet` is throwing an error before even accessing the function. It tells me it was unable to read the memory and the value for `bet` is close to `NULL` for the remainder of the program.

In conclusion, the program is not giving returning a value of 'abb' when from the function locally, nor is it saving the variable in memory. It throws garbage into the variable, but the variable is killed, and a new variable cannot be adequately initialized in `main`.

Comment: Notice the return type on your function `char  is_isogram(char phrase[])`. `if (bet == 'abb\0')` is also not going to work. You should be seeing compilation warnings for these things. If not it's time to learn to turn the warning level up.

Comment: Aside: please note that `tolower(phrase[i]);` returns a value which you ignore. It does not alter the value passed to it. Try `phrase[i] = tolower(phrase[i]);`

Comment: In `alphabet = phrase;` you are overwriting the memory pointer that `malloc` gave you. Don't do that.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. The function `is_isogram()` is declared to return a `char`, not a `char*`. The statement `alphabet = phrase` is almost certainly an error.

Comment: Please take notice of compiler warnings. The function `char  is_isogram(char phrase[])` must return `char`, yet `return alphabet;` is returning `char *`.

Comment: @msalerno Your function has long crashed befor even reaching `if (phrase == NULL)`.

Comment: regarding: `char  is_isogram(char phrase[])` and `return false;`  Please do not mix characters with booleans  They are NOT the same thing

Comment: the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  suggest removing that expression

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`,  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*`  which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `tolower(phrase[i]);`  The function `tolower()` does not modify its' operand.  rather it returns the lower case character of the character contained in the operand.  So, as written, the statement does nothing.  Suggest: `phrase[i] = tolower(phrase[i]);'

Comment: regarding: `if (bet == 'abb\0') {` the `==` cannot compare a string.  suggest using: `if ( strcmp( bet, 'abb\0') ==0 ) {`

Comment: in C, when the name of an array (in this case `alphabet[]`) is referenced, it 'degrades' to the address of the first byte in the array.

Comment: The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` and the value returned is the 'index' to the NUL byte in the string. Also, when declaring an array, such as: `if (bet == 'abb\0') {`  the declaration should be: `if( strcmp( bet, "abb" ) == 0 ) {`

Comment: regarding: `alphabet = phrase;`  this will overlay the pointer obtained by the call to `malloc()`   Suggest using: `strcpy( alphabet, phrase );`

Comment: regarding: `char *bet = is_isogram("bab\0");`  The array: "bab" will be in readonly memory, so cannot be modified.  Suggest: `sourceArray[] = "bab"l  char *bet = is_isogram( sourceArray );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- Function `is_isogram()` is defined as returning a `char`, it should instead return a string, hence type `char *`.
- `is_isogram()` attempts to modify the string pointed to by its argument. Since it is called with a string literal from `main`, this has undefined behavior, potentially a program crash.
- You allocate memory for `alphabet`, but you reset this pointer to `phrase` in the sorting loop.
- The comparison `bet == 'abb\0'` does not do what you think it does. `bet` should be a `char *` and you should use `strcmp()` to compare the string values.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *is_isogram(const char *phrase) {
    char *alphabet;
    int count1, count2, n;

    if (phrase == NULL)
        return NULL;
    alphabet = strdup(phrase);
    n = strlen(alphabet);
    for (count1 = 0; count1 < n; count1++)
        alphabet[count1] = tolower((unsigned char)alphabet[count1]);
    for (count1 = 0; count1 < n - 1; count1++) {
        for (count2 = count1 + 1; count2 < n; count2++) {
            if (alphabet[count1] > alphabet[count2]) {
                char temp = alphabet[count1];
                alphabet[count1] = alphabet[count2];
                alphabet[count2] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return alphabet;
}

int main(void) {
    char *bet = is_isogram("bab");
    if (strcmp(bet, "abb") == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I use this code: `Error C2040 'is_isogram': 'char *(const char *)` differs in levels of indirection from 'char (char *)'.' When I edit it to have differing levels of indirection and remove asterisks, there are read-write errors. These errors occur because of the indirection in the function declaration `char *is_isogram(const char *phrase)`. Please help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: I changed the prototype for `char *is_isogram(const char *phrase)`: it takes a string that it does not modify and returns an allocated copy with the letters sorted alphabetically, or more precisely in lexicographical order. The prototype in `isogram.h` must be updated accordingly.